# A problem in loading JSON data using data = json.loads(outfile.read())

Tags: python, json, python-3.8

I am using Python 3.8, and I want to load JSON data from a JSON file and then convert it to CSV.

When python executes `json.loads()`, I get this error:

> Extra data: line 17 column 1 (char 233)

I can only load one object from the JSON file, and if I have more objects, I get an error.

I use this code:

```py
import json
..
..
with open('text1.json', "r") as outfile:
        data = json.loads(outfile.read())
print(data)
```

These are the first two objects of the JSON file:

```json
{
  "Original_FIle_Name": "Original_FIle_Name",
  "Project_Name": "Project_Name",
  "Cause": "",
  "Effect": "",
  "Method": [
      "1",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "43",
      "111",
      "77"
  ],
  "Case No": "1,2"
}
{
  "Original_FIle_Name": "Original_FIle_Name",
  "Project_Name": "Project_Name",
  "Cause": "",
  "Effect": "",
  "Method": [
      "1",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "43",
      "111",
      "77"
  ],
  "Case No": "1,2"
}
```

Here's an image of `text1.json`:

[image]

Comment: Your JSON file is not valid JSON.

Comment: You're missing a comma separating the two `}{` in the middle

Comment: Check out `NDJSON`. Your file is not exactly NDJSON but if you can minify your current file, it can be used as NDJSON.